# How do I add a constraint to this table using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

I have a table called `Student` and this table has 2 columns `Student_Id` and `Is_Honor_Student` (this is a flag column either `0` or `1` to represent true/false)

I have another table called `Honor_Student` which has 2 columns `Student_Id` and `Class_Id`, along with some additional columns not relevant to this question.

Of course a 3rd table `Class` which has a `Class_Id` column.

And finally a table called `Enrollment` which has `Student_Id` and `Class_Id` referencing the `Student` and `Class` tables.

Ok, so what I want is a constraint to check that if a student is a honor student, then an entry must exist in the `Honor_Student` table BEFORE I am allowed to insert a record into the `Enrollment` table. If the student is not an honor student, then this constraint does not apply. How can I accomplish this?

By the way, I am using jdbc liquibase, so I would greatly appreciate any example using liquibase: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_check_constraint.html

But for starters I would really appreciate a kick in the right direction even using `Alter Table` or some approach that can make this possible... TECHNICALLY I think I'm looking for a "conditional" foreign key contraint with `Student_Id` and `Class_Id` referencing the `Honor_Student` table but only if it's an honor student... it's a little weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK *I think I'm looking for a "conditional" foreign key contraint* Which may not possible.

You may use [User Define Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Conditional CHECK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080823/sql-server-conditional-check-constraint) Constrains:

For Example:

UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsHonarStudentExist (
    @Student_Id INT
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Honor_Student WHERE Student_Id = @Student_Id)
        return 1
    return 0
END
```

CHECK Constrains:

```
ALTER TABLE Student WITH CHECK
ADD check (
    (Is_Honor_Student= 1 AND IsHonarStudentExist (Student_Id) = 1)
    OR
    (Is_Honor_Student= 0)
```

Note: Syntax,Data type and Query may differ based on your Database.
Above code is just an one approach.

Comment: hmm .. on that tbl where you want store data

Comment: so.. I kind of need 2 functions. One to look at student table to tell me if it's a honor student. Then another function to look at the honor_student table to tell me if there's an entry there. Then I can add a check to `Enrollment` table? Seems like it would work but it looks a little messy haha. Are these functions really needed.

Comment: you can marge all(Honor_Student ,Not Honor_Student ) in one function and directly call function in constrain You also no need to `Conditional Check`

Comment: The logic is depend on you